# Search not working properly - SP Enterprise 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, 2016, enterprise-search

I've created a new SP Enterprise 16 dev environment. I've run a crawl and everything seems to be indexing correctly via central administration. However, things will not populate in the site search, nor will the CSWP provide any results. For example, I have a photo library called "news and announcements photos" and if I change my query to search for images in that library, 0 results will populate. Can anyone give me an idea or references of what might be going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Are the photos checked in and published?

Comment: Yes, they are. Same thing for all the documents on the site as well, they also don't result in search queries. Now, some of the images will randomly show up, but I don't notice a correlation to it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With research I found that sometimes this is a problem that occurs when you create a new web application. I ended up having to delete my web application and starting over from scratch and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Check crawled items:

- Open **Central Administration**
- Go to Application Management > Manage Service Applications > **Search Service Application**
- Navigate to **Crawl Log**
- Under **Content Source** you are able to see Successes/Warnings/Errors
- Under **Diagnostic**
- Select *URL View*
- To Type a URL of host name, fill it with URL to Library and add "/*" like `https://sharepoint16.dev.cz/sites/docs*`
- You will see there crawled items and theirs state
- **If they are here, crawl is working properly you maybe just have bad query? 
   If they arent here or with some error, you should check settings of Crawling/Search Service**

[image]

[image]

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your contribution. However, as I stated in my post all of the items are being crawled correctly and are populating in central admin. I've checked the settings of the crawling/search service to no avail. Could you provide some detailed information on this perhaps I might have missed something?

Comment: If they are properly crawled, you have bad search query or bad permissions probably? There is not anything else I think. Can you provide more information? Can you add you CSWP query as we can look what are you doing? And some info about library, like URL, used content type...

Comment: Permissions are fine, as far as I am aware. I am just trying to create a CSWP to find images from a photo library that I created and nothing is populating if I search by URL or by site collection, but if I search "don't restrict results by app", I can see the images. I also noticed on my search bar within my site collection, I can't find anything. But I created an enterprise search site collection, and I can find *some* items. For example, I can find word docs and pdfs but I can't find jpegs or pngs.

Comment: I did check all my file types and they are included, FTR.

Comment: So, I created a new web application in our dev environment on a different port. Added a document, indexed, and search is working perfectly. So, I was thinking something was wrong with that web application. I created a new web application on our prod, on port 80, and still having the same issues with search as I am on dev. Is there any reason the port might have something to do with this?